# Why doesn't Power Query's M List.Contains function work the way it I thought it would?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a simple table of numbers and ABCs

[image]

When I add in a column with this line-

`List.Contains( { [ID] }, {1} )` 
Returns FALSE, even though 1 is there in the first row in the ID column.

when I do

`List.Contains( { [ID] }, 1 )` 
Returns TRUE, which is what I want.

This is a bit counter intuitive to me and not sure why - I am comparing a List with a List. so if I wrap the 1 in a {1} list, why won't this work?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [List.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-contains) function expects a single value for the second argument. That's just how it's defined.

It doesn't really make sense to use a list for the second argument *unless* it's clear how it would work if you had more than one element in the list. For such cases, there are separate functions, [List.ContainsAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-containsall) and [List.ContainsAny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-containsany) which do expect a list for the second argument.